# Can static ConcurrentHashMaps cause problems when being being kept in memory for a prolonged time?

Tags: java, multithreading, rest, memory, heap-memory

I am working on a process which takes a lot of time and hence need to update the status of the completion of the task from time to time.
I am using static ConcurrentHashMap to store the status message corresponding to the key of the process (there can be multiple similar processes at a time).
The client sends requests in a regulated interval to check the status.

I have carefully removed the key entry into the map after the process is completed. Still when I use jmap to see the heap usage, ConcurrentHashMap is apparently using a lot of it.

```
 // initialisation
 public static Map<String, String> messageMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

 // insertion
 messageMap.put(key, message);

 // removing
 message.remove(key);
```

"jmap -histo " command gave the following output

```
 num     #instances         #bytes  class name
----------------------------------------------
 1:       1730496      104093392  [C
 2:           106       96288352  [F
 3:        891190       21388560  java.lang.String
 4:          6728        5574856  [I
 5:         51676        2067040  java.util.HashMap$KeyIterator
 6:         25850        1447600  
 java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$KeyIterator
 7:         12673        1115224  java.lang.reflect.Method
 8:          2020         958680  [B
 9:         28021         896672  
 java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$Node
 10:          7793         869360  java.lang.Class
 11:         17234         689360  java.util.TreeMap$Entry
 12:         15294         611760  java.util.LinkedHashMap$Entry
 13:          5772         419336  [Ljava.util.HashMap$Node;
 14:          7797         411616  [Ljava.lang.Object;
 15:          6938         388528  java.util.LinkedHashMap
 16:           235         309056  
 [Ljava.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$Node;
 17:          9201         294432  java.util.HashMap$Node
 18:         18307         292912  java.lang.Object
 -----removed extra lines for clarity-----
```

Please suggest if this could be a cause of the problem or do I need a completely different approach for the status update.

Comment: Someone would have to look at the source code but I would not be surprised if the lengths of the underlying internal backing arrays are *never* decreased, only increased as necessary.

Comment: Static state causes problems for all sorts of additional problems. To your initial question, the usual approach would be to pull status from a `Map<String, RunningJob>` instead of constantly pushing status updates that may never be needed.

Comment: Does the memory usage go down if you do `myMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>(myMap);`?

Comment: @JamesKPolk, I am quite sure, I have checked the code multiple times. The keys are being removed from the map. I wonder what could still lead to this increase.

Comment: @chrylis, thanks for the suggestion. I will try it.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException, I am not sure how is that going to help.

Comment: @MayankYadav the idea is to work around a suspected (but unverified) possibility that HashMap does not reduce the amount of allocated memory after removing an entry. So `myMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>(myMap);` would create a new map with just enough memory to hold existing entries, and make the old map available to be garbage-collected. The idea is to execute this statement after putting a large number of entries and then removing a large number of them, and expecting that future uses of the map will hold much fewer entries

Comment: Wow! Thanks for the insight. That's something new I learned today. I will definitely try that.